# Exe program coded entirely with ascii

Tags: ascii, exe

I am trying to create a program with notepad++ using ascii characters. I was trying different characters and all I figured out was that if I use `CAN` the program stays open but I have not figured out anything else and I have searched and searched but could not find anything else on the web except for this at
[w3shcools.com](http://w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp). Right now my main goal is to make a hello world program this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use an app-builder or IDE my friend, it can really be a tedious work if you try searching all codes to complete your program. You don't only need to probe them out, you also need to understand the program and syntax structure and working of a .exe program.